# C++ fread() reports back right size read, but buffer is missing data on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

Scenario: I have a file that is 8,203,685 bytes long in binary, and I am using fread() to read in the file.

Problem: Hexdumping the data after the fread() on both Linux and Windows yields different results. Both hexdump files are the same size, but on Linux it matches the original input file that went in, whereas on Windows starting at byte 8,200,193 the rest of the hexdump contains 0's.

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
  FILE * fp = fopen("input.exe", "rb");
  unsigned char * data = NULL;
  long size = 0;

  if (fp)
  {
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    data = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);

    size_t read_bytes = fread(data, 1, size, fp);
    // print out read_bytes, value is equal to size

    // Hex dump using ofstream. Hexdump file is different here on Windows vs
    // on Linux. Last ~3000 bytes are all 0's on Windows.
    std::ofstream out("hexdump.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(data), size);
    out.close();

    FILE * out_file = fopen("hexdump_with_FILE.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(data, 1, size, out_file);
    fflush(out_file);
    fclose(out_file);
  }

  if (fp) fclose(fp);
  if (data) free(data);

  return 0;
}
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before, or have an idea of what might be causing the behavior that I am seeing?

P.S. Everything works as expected when using ifstream and its read function

Thanks!

Comment: `C/C++` is UB..

Comment: `fread` is a standard C function, not C++.

Comment: there's too much of the code missing that might be the problem - you should flesh it out so it's a [mcve]

Comment: @SouravGhosh What does UB means?

Comment: @Olaf I understand. The reason why I included C++ in the title was just to let people know that I do have the option of using ifstream, and I am using C++ compiler, and C++ can use fread as well

Comment: @ChrisTurner Added in some more source code

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends.

Comment: You use the wrong types all over the place, also mixing signedness. `ftell()` returns `long`, `fread()` returns `size_t` (which is unsigned). As for the shown code being the source of the problem: I don't believe this. Still, use the correct types to be sure.

Comment: @Olaf according to the comments, it's still C++ code.

Comment: One possible reason for unexpected results would be mixing C++ `iostream` with C `stdio` (or even with platform-specific direct file access like `read()` on POSIX)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Yes, changed the tag. Heck if askers would read the tag wikis!

Comment: What bytes are in the missing last 3000? It could be that your file is corrupted on disk. Unlikely that fread() has a bug.

Comment: I do appreciate the accuracy, and I do understand where you're coming from, but in the case of size_t, using an int in this case still works fine as the size does not exceeds the max size limit for an int. I'm more focused on understanding why fread() yields different result rather than that my type might not be correct, but it contains the correct value.

Comment: so you are saying that code you dont show reports that not all the data was read. Well, please show that code. If you look at `data` in your debugger does it look correct? At least work out if its the read or the write thats wrong

Comment: I think it's unrewarding reasoning about *possible* problems with just a bit of "*pseudo code*". Voting to close here, as a question seeking debugging help should contain an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you mean by what bytes are missing? The file that I read in isn't corrupted, and I did a binary compare between the copy that exists on Windows and the copy that exists on Linux and they match.

Comment: The checksum calculation that is taking place is a black-box that I do not have source code to, but I do know that it takes in the data buffer, and the size. This function outputs a checksum that matches the checksum contained in the file header on Linux, but it does not on Windows. So using the same code on both platform, Windows yields a different checksum. Since the function only takes in two arguments, I checked both, and the size matches on both platform, but the data does not.

Comment: Is the added logic enough information?

Comment: @ThomasPhan the problem persists that it's *impossible to reproduce* in the current form. I don't believe that `fread()` doesn't work correctly. The wrong types you're using **are** a problem, but probably not on win32. Still you should fix that. But on your actual problem, we can just *guess*, and that's not a good thing for a stackoverflow question. You should really try to create an MCVE.

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question to contain a new program that will produce this problem on my computer. Please give me a bit.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is the file is opened in text mode. But there is `"rb"` in the example.

Comment: Hello, I have completely reedit the question. I can still reproduce the problem on my computer with this code, and both ways of hexdumping the data yields the same result with missing bytes at the end.

Comment: If you share both hexdumps, we can easily check what is the difference between them

Comment: As much as I would like to, that is impossible. I can't share the hexdump of the executable. I do apologize.

The only difference I can personally see is that the hexdump on the Linux side matches the original input file, while the hexdump on the Windows side does not. I will edit the question to include the exact size and when the missing bytes occur.

Comment: If you checksum all but the last missing bytes, does the checksums differ?

Comment: 8200192 is aligned to 4k... Very suspicious.

Comment: @geza Yes the checksum would still be different because the checksum of the original file is calculated from the size of the entire file, so if I just calculate the checksum without the missing bytes, it will differ. But I'm refraining from mentioning the checksum stuff now since it just confuses others more and it doesn't contribute to the problem.

Comment: Several things to try: does it happen with some other file? Does it happen with another compiler? Which compiler do you use, btw.?

Comment: I meant to compare **both** with the missing bytes, of course. Ie., is the only difference the last ~3000 bytes? Otherwise, are the to read buffers the same? It seems a c library bug to me (which is usually rare, especially for something heavily used stuff, like fread).

Comment: `out.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(data), size);` - you need to use `read_bytes` instead of `size`. Same with `fwrite(data, 1, size, out_file);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Would it matter in this case besides being "more accurate"? I'm currently printing out read_bytes and it is the same size as the file that is being read in.

Comment: @geza To answer your question, interestingly using another file that is roughly the same size (slightly smaller) also has ~3000 bytes missing, and the byte where the mismatch occurs is also aligned to 4k.

Comment: @ThomasPhan `fread` is not guaranteed to read the number of bytes requested. That is why it has a return value to specify the number actually read. For completeness, you should be calling `fread` in a loop until the entire `size` is consumed

Comment: @remy: true but OP claims that `read_bytes == size` . Obviously, `assert(read_bytes == size);` would be more convincing.

Comment: I've decided to go with std::ifstream read which seems to work consistently on both platform for me.

But for future reference, I did some more testing using fread() on smaller chunks in a loop instead of on the entire file, the fread() would work on certain size chunks (ones that are aligned 4k) while not working on other size chunks. And for the ones that work, it's always the last bytes/buffer that are missing.

Since it doesn't seems like this issue is happening for anyone else here, I'm more inclined to think that the issue is with the Windows computer that I'm running this on.